# RewriteCond for query parameters in .htaccess files

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, query-string

I have to write some Rewrite Rules and I need to make a check based on my query parameters.

The public url is something like this `abc.com/lmn/xyz.json` and there is an optional parameter `optparam`.

This is what I want to achieve:

If `optparam` is present and `not equal to false`, the conditions have to fail and carry on with other rules.

After reading through few blogs and posts, I have a very faint idea about these rules. So tried this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^optparam $ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^optparam=false$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^lmn/xyz.json$ xyz.json
```

But the RewriteRule is applied even when I send the param value to be true.

Please tell me what I am missing here.

Thanks in advance!

Examples:

```
abc.com/lmn/xyz.json ==> Rule should fire
abc.com/lmn/xyz.json?optparam ==> Rule should not fire
abc.com/lmn/xyz.json?optparam=false ==> Rule should fire
abc.com/lmn/xyz.json?optPARAM=hfjsgzjrg ==> Rule should not fire
abc.com/lmn/xyz.json?optParam=FALSE ==> Rule should fire
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your rule to this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(optparam=false)?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^lmn/xyz\.json$ xyz.json [L,NC]
```

Comment: What if there is no `optparam` at all?

Comment: `?!false$` doesn't it fire the rule when value is say, true? Should it just be `?false$`, Also, how will I combine this with no parameter at all?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think an additional check of `optparam` not present at all is required. Tried this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^$|!^optparam$|^optparam=false$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^lmn/xyz\.json$ xyz.json [L,NC]
```

This seems to work for me. But is there any way to further shorten this condition? I believe I am not using regex to its full potential here.